# Xorg.bin uses 100% CPU randomly (mostly after switching TTY), with i915

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg

I'm on Arch Linux, 64bit, on ThinkPad x201, and it's using (I think) an integrated graphics chip in the Intel i5 CPU.

Sometimes, Xorg entirely hogs one core for several minutes. It's entirely frozen and I have to kill it via SysRq, or use SysRq+R and then switch tty to try to debug it..

This happens randomly on it's own, and also briefly after startup. Triggers include TTY switching, and unplugging/plugging keyboard or USB hub.

After a couple minutes, it becomes responsive again, but it's bad for my battery life, and I have to use SysRq to kill it.

I'm looking for a fix, workaround, or atleast info on where to report it, and what exactly to report. There seems to be no centralised X bugtracker.

*Here's some of my debugging attempts:*

It seems to be stuck in a loop of: (I got this using strace command)

**strace**

```
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}, NULL) = 0
select(256, [1 5 7 8 12 14 15 21 23 29 30 31 32 33 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57], NULL, NULL, {0, 0}) = 2 (in [31 39], left {0, 0})
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, {it_interval={0, 5000}, it_value={0, 5000}}, NULL) = 0
recvmsg(39, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"!\0\4\0\201\0\0\0\f\0y\1\1\0\0\0!\0\4\0\201\0\0\0\34\0y\1\1\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 68
writev(39, [{"\1\2v\251\0\0\0\0\5\0\340\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32}], 1) = 32
recvmsg(39, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\207\10\7\0\0\1\7\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0y\1", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 28
writev(39, [{"\1\3w\251\364\4\0\0\0\0\10\377\7\0\0\32\32\10\307\1\370\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10"..., 40}], 1) = 40
writev(39, [{"\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\1\1\0\0\2\1\0\0\1\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\3\3\0\0\2\2\0\0"..., 5064}], 1) = 5064
recvmsg(39, 0x7fff5c82aee0, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Here are some errors found in my dmesg, which appear to be related to the freeze.

**dmesg**

```
[  136.322574] [drm:ilk_display_irq_handler] *ERROR* Pipe B FIFO underrun
[  136.322583] [drm:ibx_irq_handler] *ERROR* PCH transcoder B FIFO underrun
```

**/var/log/Xorg.log.0**

There is nothing of interest there, only warnings or errors are

```
[     3.890] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[     5.665] (WW) evdev: SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard: ignoring absolute axes.
[    10.609] (WW) evdev: SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard: ignoring absolute axes.
```

**Graphics card (from lshw)**

*At least I believe this is the graphics card, not sure.*

```
 *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:24 memory:f2000000-f23fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8)
```

**CPU info**

```
Handle 0x0006, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: None
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Other
    Manufacturer: GenuineIntel
    ID: 52 06 02 00 FF FB EB BF
    Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz
    Voltage: 1.3 V
    External Clock: 133 MHz
    Max Speed: 2400 MHz
    Current Speed: 2400 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: None
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x000A
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x000B
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x000C
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Core Count: 2
    Core Enabled: 2
    Thread Count: 4
    Characteristics: None
```

**Gfx driver i915 version**

```
~ $ pacfind i915

    extra/xf86-video-intel 2.99.916-3 (xorg-drivers xorg) [installed]
        X.org Intel i810/i830/i915/945G/G965+ video drivers
```

**Xorg version**

```
~ $ pacinfo xorg-server
Name           : xorg-server
Version        : 1.16.2-1
Architecture   : x86_64
```

Comment: It's a bug in your video driver, either the kernel part or the X part. Or possibly even a firmware bug. Try installing more recent versions. Or older versions.

Comment: yeah, and so you close it. Useful.

Comment: If you need help, you need to give us some information about your system. At the very least: your exact model of graphics card and which driver you're running. Then… we could google for a similar problem with the same hardware and driver version, which you can do by yourself anyway.

Comment: Now there is tons of more information, so you can reopen it. I tried to google it, so I think your search will be fruitless as well, but maybe you know better where to look.

Comment: why is it still closed????

Comment: @MightyPork - we close Q's until they are in better shape. Closing is as much to help the OP as it is to help our community from wasting their time asking for all this basic info and being forced to guess what your issues are.  As it stands it's in much better shape now so I'll reopen it, but unless anyone has this hardware your issue will likely still not be resolvable. I own a lot of Thinkpad hardware and you generally have to solve your own issues via research. It's just how it is.

Comment: @MightyPork - to help point you in the right direction I would focus on the `dmesg` output to start. There are many threads related to that, some w/ Thinkpad h/w too. Such as this one: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184857

Comment: @MightyPork - I wouldn't assume it's a X bug and wouldn't bother trying to file a bug report for that. Your issue is almost always going to be a video driver + hardware issue.

Comment: @MightyPork - also regarding closings. It requires 5 reopen votes or a moderator's vote to reopen a closed Q. If no one has voted to reopen this then that's likely telling you something about the quality of the Q, even after the edits.